# Can't load desktop environment with startx

Tags: xorg, nvidia, i3

I'm facing a problem that I've never seen before. I want to load i3 with my new installation of Arch Linux but when I launch startx, the tty is freezing with no error. I've checked the log of xorg, I didn't see any error.
[image: message when launching startx]

EDIT : 
There is a IMG of the output of . xinitrc when I comment `exec i3` [image: output of xinitrc]

Comment: what does your .xinitrc say?

Comment: If I run the script .xinitrc it say i3 cannot open display. I've never seen this on my last i3 installation.

Comment: what exactly is in your ~/.xinitrc?  do you have "exec i3" listed somewhere in there?  If you haven't copied a .xinitrc file over to your home directory, do this first: cp /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc ~/.xinitrc

Comment: I've copied the file and commented the line with twm xclock and xterm. Then I had exec i3.

Comment: .xinitrc is just a config file, I wouldn't try to run it like a script.  try making your ~/.xinitrc file look like this (just uncomment the "i3" line).  then run "startx" and see if there are any errors: https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Proper_~/.xinitrc_File

Comment: @bgregs same thing than image 1. It just show me recaps lines and then freeze my tty

Comment: hmmm strange.  I'm out of ideas, but found this online, I hope it helps! https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/xorg-hangs-before-starting-with-no-error-4175490442/

Comment: If you aren't seeing anything other than the text console then the error is with the X server, not with what you put in `.xinitrc`. Has X worked before on this installation? Have you tried a display manager? Post the complete [Xorg log file](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xorg#General).

Answer (score 0):

The answer was a problem with the Nvidia drivers. Thanks to @bgregs for the additional help.
So in order to solve it, I've uninstall the nvidia drivers then uninstall all xorg programs. 
After reinstall xorg and configure it for your own.

Answer (score -2):

The DISPLAY is not defined correctly in xorg.conf, or the user's environment, perhaps?
Thus, the repeated message:  Can't open display, DISPLAY is not set
Not sure, but investigating that angle may help you.

Comment: Well I thought about it, but I've looked around for "regular" xorg.conf file and I've didn't see any lines with a display parameters. I've also looked on the x.org website, same. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @DataHearth did you look at the last link I provided in the comments above?  looks like some other users have experienced this same issue with bad Nvidia drivers

Comment: `DISPLAY` is set automatically, and you can't know the value in advance. That error is not from the relevant part of the question anyway.

Comment: @bgregs yes, I'll try next day and remove the Nvidia drivers. I'll update my post if it'll works.